# How to Strip Out the Text From And Html String in Java

Tags: java, html, string, parsing

I want to analyze the structure of the html pages. For a page I have it as a string and I want to strip out the text and to keep only the html structure. I don't want to use a DOM parser, and I need something robust which works on regular html not only xhtml. I know regular expressions are good enough to strip out html tags from a string, but can they be used to strip out the text and to keep only the html tags?

Do you know any other option/framework I could use?

Comment: I would definitively go after a DOM parser...

Comment: The reason for which I wanted to avoid a DOM parse is the fact that I wanted to use the resulted html as a string not as a DOM. However, I can use a DOM parser to strip out the text then to get it as as an string. That works too, I just want to know what other options I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know any other option/framework I could use?

You might want to look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org).  Seems to be designed to solve exactly this type of problem.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is an easy way to do this using regex.

[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) is a pretty neat HTML parser with a small footprint and a single jar without additional external libraries.

Comment: I've been using Jericho before and I tried for my specific task but it seems not so well fitted for changing html structure. For example you need a special TextExtractor class to access the text the html tags. It seems hard to remove the text in each node since there appears not to exist any method for changing inner html. I should give a try to JSoup which seems better equipped for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you've stripped out tags before, you know the basic gist is to strip out everything between < and >. Stripping out text is very similar, except you're stripping out everything between > and <. So yes, regular expressions would serve you very well in stripping out the text and leaving just the tags. They could also be used to strip out tag attributes as well if you didn't want to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a decent start.  I don't have much experience with HTML so I don't know if there is anything else to parse out of the string besides < tags >.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String html = "<body> text text text text </body>";
    String htmlTags = null;
    char c;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < html.length() ; i++){
        c = html.charAt(i);
        if(tagStart(Character.toString(c))){
            for(int j = i ; j < html.length() ; j++){
                if(htmlTags != null){
                    htmlTags += Character.toString(html.charAt(j));
                }else{
                    htmlTags = Character.toString(html.charAt(j));
                }
                c = html.charAt(j);
                if(tagStop(Character.toString(c))){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean tagStart(String check){
    if(check.equals("<")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private static boolean tagStop(String check){
    if(check.equals(">")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good start If i don't have any other robust method. There are a few things for which I'd try DOM or any other parser/library, even regex before of direct parsing. Firstly I would have to keep the contained "text" in certain tags like <script>, <style>. Second of all I'd like to avoid to parse wrong un-encoded signs < > put directly in text.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
pageSource.replaceAll(">.*<", "><");
```

Should get you started.